# Json parsing error: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I am new to programming and I have small problem i am trying to make an app that will use json to read flickr api but i am getting the error mention in the description i was looking around but none of the solutions worked so i came here to ask

```
public class JSONPareser {
    final String TAG = "JSONParser";

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

that is my parser class and here is when i am calling json object

```
public class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne";
        JSONPareser pareser = new JSONPareser();
        String jsonStr = pareser.makeServiceCall(url);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    FlickrModel model = new FlickrModel();
                    model.setLink(obj.getString("link"));
                    model.setDescription(obj.getString("description"));
                    model.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                    model.setAuthor(obj.getString("author"));
                    model.setTags(obj.getString("tags"));
                    flickrList.add(model);

                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

thank you so much

Comment: A tip for you, you dont need runOnUiThread from onPostExecute method;

Comment: can you paste the response as it shows xml response is coming .. I think the url schema is incorrect or server is not up so sending xml instead of json in response ... The min requirement for JsonParser to parse is the response string has to be in json format.

Answer (score 0):

Your service seens to be returning a XML instead of JSON, see the header